# Oxidation of alkenes and alkynes by Chromic Oxide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox

As far as I know, $\ce{CrO3}$ doesn't effect the $\mathrm{\pi}$ bonds in an inert medium like pyridine. Would $\ce{CrO3}$ in acidic medium reduce alkynes to have the same products as acidified, warm $\ce{KMnO4}$ would have? Or does it produce diketones similar to reductive ozonolysis?